# Printing files vs. Printing of files

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

When Printing is a subject (nominative to a verb) what is the correct option:
1) Printing [PDF/Word/TXT/JPG] files or
2) Printing of [PDF/Word/TXT/JPG] files

For example, 
Batch printing [of?] PDF files is a new feature of our program.

Are there any special cases, on how to say print(ing) + documents, books, filetypes, etc.?

Please refer to a guide where I can read more on this. Thanks!

Comment: You can use either, with a slight shift of emphasis.  'Batch printing XYZ files' emphasizes that the printing is a new feature.  'Batch printing *of*  XYZ files' emphasizes that the file formats are newly available for printing.

Answer (score 1):

As Yosef Baskin mentions in a comment, the difference is a slight shift in focus.

If you say "batch printing PDF files", the focus is on the files.  Printing is what you do to them.  In another sentence, you might talk about some other action you take with PDF files.

If you say "batch printing **of** PDF files", the focus is on the printing.  PDF files are what you print.  In another sentence, you might talk about printing a different type of file.

Answer (score 0):

Printing files would be used in more active grammatical structures, printing OF files would be used in more passive grammatical structures.

Comment: If still in doubt, take a look at [Paramedic Method](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/635/01/).

Comment: I'd prefer '_printing files_ is more verby and _[the] printing of files_ more nouny'; active vs passive has to do with a definite construction and alternation.